# does every limit point of T1 subspace A has a convergent sequence to it?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $(X, T_X)$ be a $T_1$ topology. Then is this true: $\forall A \subset X$, $\forall$ limit point $a$ of $A$, $\exists$ sequence $a_n \in A$ that converges to $a$?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in a $T_1$ space we can just say that for every neighbourhood $O$ of $x$, the set $O \cap A$ is infinite.

A simple example: let $X=\Bbb R$ in the co-countable topology and $A=(0,1)$ and $x = 2$. Then **no** sequence from $A$ converges to $x$ despite all points of $X$ being a limit point of $A$.